# GIS Application in Apache HTTP Server (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web, gis

I have an Apache HTTP Server, using PHP and MySQL
What is the best tool to build a GIS appliction?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very very broad question. This site is for specific problems.

Comment: Try asking this on http://gis.stackexchange.com or possibly http://programmers.stackexchange.com But you will need to be more specific about what your GIS application needs to do. GIS is a massive area. Will you need geospatial queries, route finding, interactive maps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapserver.

It's Open source, it's designed to be used with Apache, Php and the rest of the Lamp stack, and well it's pretty darn good too:

http://mapserver.org/